# Jailbreak before iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak

Does anyone think that we can expect a jailbreak between iOS 7.0.6 and iOS 8? Or will we just have to wait it out? My iPad 3rd gen is running iOS 7.1 and I can't find a jailbreak for it.

Comment: So your question basically means; will there be an iOS 7 jailbreak? There's already one for iOS 7.1.

Comment: @Rob There isn't a jailbreak for 7.1? Only 7.0.x

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. There is no jailbreak for iOS 7.1, that I know of. The newest one is 7.0.6. I think there may be one for iPhone 4 or older, but I'm not sure. Now, I don't know if this means that I can use this on my iPad 3rd gen or not. Which is what I want to jailbreak. But I know it won't work for my iPhone 5s. Luckily that didn't get updated, so it's still Jailbroken. Do you know of one? I'll edit my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Evad3rs jailbreak team:

> Q: When I can make jailbreak 7.1? 
>   A: We don't have such information.
>   Wait.

As you don't want to ruin your Apple devices, you should not download any Jailbreak tools from external sources except the **real deal**.

E.g. Evad3rs, Redsn0w

Comment: Thank you. That's pretty much what I have found everywhere else so far. I hoped someone here might have a more definite answer. Wishful thinking, I guess.